# SVN Filename Failing

Tags: tortoisesvn

I discovered something strange with Tortoise svn. File names that include "Jsp" in the filename do not properly go into the repository. For example, the Java file TestMyJsp.java goes into the repository as TestMyjsp (lower case j and no .java file extension). Because of this, the local file cannot be committed or updated. Merely changing the J of Jsp to a K will make it work as expected. Any insights?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, you should file a JIRA [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/reportbug.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is not really a SVN problem, it is because Windows is not case sensitive with file names.

You will need to rename your file to TestMyJsp-tmp.java, remove the old one and commit this changes.

Then, you can rename and commit it again with the real name.

It happened to me a lot of time. The same appear inside Eclipse on windows too.